# XSD error: attribute name required but missing

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I assume this error may be because of a missing tag, but I can't seem to get it.
This is the code, the error is at the `xs:complexType` line:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Artwork"/>
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="media" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="created" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="display" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:schema>
```

[image: This is the error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<xs:element name="Artwork"/>
```

to

```
<xs:element name="Artwork">
```

and add `</xs:element>` after `</xs:complexType>`

Because the `xs:element` element is empty, the `xs:complexType` is a direct child of `xs:schema` and therefore requires a `name` attribute.

Comment: Tried that before and it says that there's a premature end of data in 
the line with the schema (first line) that's why i added it in

Comment: @MikhailFoster: This answer is correct (+1).  Execution error, perhaps?  Compare what you changed with the [correctly updated XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61219741/290085).

Comment: Yeah i compared it and saw what i did wrong. Thanks so much understanding this  a bit more

Answer (score 0):

If you make the corrections that @MichaelKay [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218231/290085), your error will go away.  Here are the changes correctly applied:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Artwork">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="media" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="created" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="display" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```